# select max between two columns in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have dateSend Column and dateEdit Column in product table, i can select max dateSend with this code:

```
(from pro in Products.ToList()
select new { pro.DateSend }).Max();
```

but i have max between dateSend and dateEdit, please help me.

Comment: What is the type of DateSend? From your remark below I assume it is `DateTime?`... Is that correct?

Comment: DateSend = Datetime & DateEdit = Datetime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(from pro in Products.ToList()
let max = Max(pro.DateSend, pro.DateEdit)
select max).Max()


static DateTime? Max(DateTime? a, DateTime? b)
{
    if (!a.HasValue && !b.HasValue) return a;  // doesn't matter

    if (!a.HasValue) return b;  
    if (!b.HasValue) return a;

    return a.Value > b.Value ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Error: Nullable object must have a value. because, dateEdit is empty

Comment: i use this code: let max = pro.DateEdit != null && pro.DateSend < pro.DateEdit ? pro.DateEdit.Value : pro.DateSend

Answer (score 8):

If you're not opposed to ditching the query syntax it's simpler to do:

```
DateTime max = Products.Max(p=>p.DateSend > p.DateEdit ? p.DateSend : p.DateEdit);
```

Comment: Error: Nullable object must have a value. because, dateEdit is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
((from pro in Products.ToList()
select pro.DateSend).Union(
from pro2 in Products.ToList()
select pro.DateEdit
)).Max();
```

Comment: Why scan the collection twice when you can easily select the higher of the two columns for each item?

Comment: You're right, it's not the most optimal way. Your answer is indeed a better way of doing it. Added my vote. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

**Same code but with One LinQ**

```
   (From pro in Products.ToList
    Let max = {pro.DateSend, pro.DateEdit}.Max
    select max).Max
```

If pro items not a valid DateTime, It will crash or return unexpected result.

**Other solution(Parsing the Products list items):**

```
 (From pro in Products.ToList
    Let DSend as DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Iif(ValidDateTime(pro.DateSend), pro.DateSend, DateTime.MinValue))
    Let DEdit as DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Iif(ValidDateTime(pro.DateEdit), pro.DateEdit, DateTime.MinValue))
    Let MaxDate as DateTime= {DSend, DEdit}.Max
    select MaxDate).Max

private function ValidDateTime(ByVal Dat as Object) as Boolean
   if Dat Is Nothing OrElse IsDbNull(Dat) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dat)  then
      return false
   end if

   return true
end function
```

You can replace the ValidDateTime with an "Iif".

Other example returning max value of Double items, but in the personalized object(MyObject), items are String type.

```
  (From Item as MyObject in MyListOfObject
    Let Frec as Double = Convert.ToDouble(Iif(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Frecuency),0,Item.Frecuency))
    Let Pot as Double = Convert.ToDouble(Iif(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Power),0,Item.Power))
    Let max as Double= {Frec, Pot}.Max
    select max).Max
```

**Recap**

1. Declare Column Items separately. Parse It(If you need)
2. Create an Item for store the max value of the row(all columns)
3. Create an Array, put in all declared Items and asign array to the before declared item(Item created in step 2)
4. Append in the end of the array the Max property like this: {Item1, Item2,...}.Max
5. Create Select fr return the Max item
6. Append in the end the linq Max property. (MyLinQ).Max

I hope this code helps to someone.
Sorry for my English.