# Linq query to return a data structure holding max DateTime property of each passed object

Tags: c#, linq

A function gets a list of Person objects. Each Person has a `Guid` property and multiple `DateTime?` properties.

I need a LINQ query to return any kind of data structure (I thought about a dictionary, but it is not mandatory) holding each Person object and its respective max `DateTime?` property.

So I have:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid id {get; set;}
    public DateTime? Activity1 {get; set;}
    public DateTime? Activity2 {get; set;}
    public DateTime? Activity3 {get; set;}
}
```

And I need:

```
//{{ 1st Person's Guid, 1st Person's max DateTime}, { 2nd Person's Guid, 2nd Person's max DateTime}, ...}
```

Comment: There are three DateTime which you want to filter?

Comment: @AmmarAhmed, I need to get the max one out of them.

Comment: Something similar done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669782/select-max-between-two-columns-in-linq.

Comment: Is this going to be used as part of an EF query, or just on in-memory operations? The answers would vary wildly depending on that.

Comment: @krillgar, in-memory, but since you asked, I'd be happy to examine the differences.

Comment: The difference is that anything you write for EF has to be serializable into SQL. So that limits things like reflection, unless you somehow do that outside the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for if the id is unique per each person:

```
var result=persons.ToDictionary(p=>p.id,
                                p=>new{
                                       Person=p,
                                       MaxDate=new[]{p.Activity1,
                                                     p.Activity2,
                                                     p.Activity3}.Max()});
```

You could convert the three properties into an array and get the max value using Linq.

Comment: Except all Activity properties are nullable.

Comment: @Evk, to avoid to deal the nullable issue I decided go for another solution using an array ;)

Comment: You're missing the `()` after `Max`

Comment: Thanks @juharr ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you don´t know what are the `DateTime?` properties, you would need to use reflection to loop through the properties of this type.

Also, you could return a list of `Tuple<Person, DateTime?>`. Here is the code:

```
public static List<Tuple<Person, DateTime?>> GetMax(List<Person> personList)
{
    List<Tuple<Person, DateTime?>> list = new List<Tuple<Person, DateTime?>>();

    foreach (Person p in personList)
    {
        DateTime? maxDate = null;

        var properties = p.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                DateTime? date = (DateTime?)property.GetValue(p);
                maxDate = Max(maxDate, date);
            }
        }

        list.Add(new Tuple<Person, DateTime?>(p, maxDate));
    }

    return list;
}

static DateTime? Max(DateTime? a, DateTime? b)
{
    if (!a.HasValue && !b.HasValue) return a;  // doesn't matter

    if (!a.HasValue) return b;
    if (!b.HasValue) return a;

    return a.Value > b.Value ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: I got the `Max(DateTime? a, DateTime? b)` function from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669782/select-max-between-two-columns-in-linq).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a one-line full **LINQ** solution.

Since you didn't mention that the number of `DateTime?` fields could vary, I hardcoded them into my solution.

**However**, if you wish to use a dynamic amount of `DateTime?` fields, I would advise you against **reflection**. **Reflection** is a last resort solution and you could solve the problem of the dynamic amount of `DateTime?` fields with a `List<>` or a `Dictionary<>`.

Let me know if you need a solution also for the dynamic amount of `DateTime?` fields.

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
Dictionary<Person, DateTime?> MaxDateTime = People.ToDictionary(x => x, x => new[] { x.Activity1, x.Activity2, x.Activity3 }.Where(y => y.HasValue).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(y => new Nullable<DateTime>(y.Value)));
```

**Edit**: Dynamic solution

The best way to store a dynamic amount of `DateTime` objects is to add them to a `List<>`. You don't need individual properties within the class and also will not lose the indexation of the `DateTime` object, since objects are indexed in a `List<>` by default. You can also add them manually at the desired index.

With a `List<>` you can omit the `Nullable<>` type from your class. If an activity doesn't exist, you just simply won't add it to your `List<>`. When you get the `Dictionary<>` of the people and their maximum `DateTime`, it might occur that they don't have any activities. So in this case, a `Nullable<>` is needed to prevent the default value of the `DateTime` to be set.

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Activities { get; set; }

    public void AddActivity(int Index, DateTime DateTime) => Activities.Insert(Index, DateTime);
}

public void Main()
{
    List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
    Dictionary<Person, DateTime?> MaxDateTimeOfPeople = People.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.Activities.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(y => new Nullable<DateTime>(y)));
}
```

Comment: Yes, a dynamic solution would be great.

Comment: I updated my solution to your needs. If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Oh, I had a different understanding of "dynamic". The thing is, the class structure is given, though it may have additional activity properties. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Then you have two choices: 
1. You stick to my first solution and whenever a new property is added, you add it to the array in the LINQ solution.
2. I don't recommend reflection, since it is a last resort but if there is no other solution, then you should choose that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = persons.Select(person => new { person, maxDate = new [] { person.Activity1, person.Activity2, person.Activity3 }.Max() });
```